# create extension method in linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

How to create an extension method to the string to get a sum
create  Sumstring extension method

```
List<myclass> obj=new List<myclass>()
{
    new myclass(){ID=1,name="ali",number=1},
    new myclass(){ID=1,name="karimi",number=2},
    new myclass(){ID=2,name="mohammad",number=4},
    new myclass(){ID=2,name="sarbandi",number=5},
};

var query = (from p in obj 
             group p by p.ID into g
             select new 
             { id = g.Key, sum = g.Sumstring(p => p.name) }).ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource=query;
```

I connect to the database
 What is the code

Comment: What's the sum of a string? Concatenation?

Comment: what are the inputs/outputs of `sumstring`?

Answer (score 0):

You've not specified what `SumString` really returns, but looks like you're talking about string concatenation of all source collection elements.

It can be easily done using `String.Join` method:

```
public static class EnumerableOfString
{
    public static string SumString<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, string> selector, string separator = null)
    {
        return String.Join(separator ?? string.Empty, source.Select(i => selector(i)));
    }
}
```

That method allows following calls:

```
g.SumString(p => p.name)
```

with `string.Empty` as default deparator and with custom separator specified:

```
g.SumString(p => p.name, ",")
```

Comment: tanks OK
But when I connect to the database, we can change the code
What is the code

Comment: I connect to the database, we can change the code What is the code

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is concatenate the strings in that group you can use the built-in [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) function:

```
var query = (from p in obj 
             group p by p.ID into g
             select new 
             { id = g.Key, sum = g.Aggregate((tot, next) => tot + "," + next) }
            ).ToList();
```